# How an Interface passed to a class can call a method from that class?

Tags: java

Suppose I have the following interface

```
public interface I {
    public int evaluate();
}
```

and the following class

```
public class A {
    // ...
    public int getX(){}
    public int evaluateX(I model){
        return model.evaluate();
    }
}
```

then, can I have an implementation of `I` such that

```
class Model implements I {
    @Override
    public int evaluate() {
        return getX() + 1;
    }
}
```

in which the implementation is calling a method of class `A`?

I know of Reflection but I would like to know about a static technique.
Thank you

Comment: You have the relationship between Model and I, but where is the relationship between I and getX?

Comment: I don't think there is an other way of doing that than using reflection. You have to think about the fact, that not every class you're calling a function from your Model from must implement the function. Why don't you simply let the class A implement the interface instead?

Comment: Meaningful names would help us understand what you're trying to do. If you want the interface method I.evaluate() to call `A.getX()`, then pass an A object to `I.evaluate()` -- `class I {public int evaluate( A myA ); }`. Optionally, you could pass the A object as an interface type, to allow I.evaluate() to operate on multiple definitions -- `class I { public int evaluate( IX myX ); }`.

Comment: @Dakoda that is exactly my question. How to specify the relationship then?

Comment: @Endzeit I was carious actually to find a different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use lmbdas? Looks like your example is a good candidate for it.

```
public interface I {
    public int evaluate( Supplier<Integer> s);
}

public static class A {

    public int getX(){return 5;}

    public int evaluateX(I model){

        return model.evaluate( () -> getX() );
    }
}

public static class Model implements I {

    @Override
    public int evaluate(Supplier<Integer> s) {
        return s.get() + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is no.

Also, this would look like tight coupling, as the interface would have to know about the classes it's being injected into.

What you may want to do is parametrize the `evaluate` method and its implementations with an `int`, so you could pass it as `getX()` when invoking in class `A`, then increment by `1` in your `Model` class's `evaluate` implementation.

**Edit**

As suggested by [Andy Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/202009/andy-thomas), you may want to furtherly generalize.

Instead of parametrize `evaluate` with an `int`, you could parametrize it with an interface declaring the `int getX()` method (which `A` would subsequently implement).

In turn, `A` would invoke `model.evaluate(this)`, and `Model`'s `evaluate` implementation would change into something like `return myGivenArgument.getX() + 1`.

Up to you to decide whether this is necessary based on the context.

Comment: The real answer is yes, and is simple as passing an instance of the class to the interface method as an argument.

Comment: @AndyThomas agreed this is a better generalized solution, although it might turn into something a little overkill. You'd require an interface declaring `getX` which `A` implements, then declare `evaluate(MyNewInterface foo)`.

Comment: @AndyThomas If you're passing the concrete class as an argument one should think about the reason even using an interface at all. If you're coupling that tight the interface becomes merely obsolete and the functionality might as well be implemented in the class. To prevent that I'd recommend using two interfaces instead, one let'S call it L being implemented by the class A, and the second interface I expecting the interface L as argument to it's function.

Comment: @Endzeit - As always, you could use an interface to support multiple implementations. In the OP's case, there could be multiple models.